# Ошибка в строке с переменной n_outliers в R

Tags: r

Практикуясь с датасетом ChildSpeaks из пакета Stat2Data в R, вижу ошибку "Error: unexpected symbol in: "n_outliers". В чем проблема?

```
library(ggplot2)
child_mod <- lm(Gesell ~ Age, ChildSpeaks)
child_diag <- data.frame(fortify(child_mod), ChildSpeaks)

D_cut_off <- 4 / (nrow(child_diag) - 2) # Пороговое значение расстояния Кука

gg_Cook <- ggplot(child_diag, aes(x = 1:nrow(child_diag), y = .cooksd) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = D_cut_off)) # График расстояния Кука от порядкового номера наблюдений

n_outliers <- sum(child_diag$.cooksd > D_cut_off) # Сколько наблюдений-выбросов?
```

Comment: да при вводе этой конструкции указывает, что таковых два значения. собственно, копирую из консоли:

> sum(child_diag$.cooksd > D_cut_off)
[1] 2

Comment: а, так у вас скобка не закрыта в строке, где вызываете ggplot(). посчитайте количество открывающих и закрывающих скобок: они у вас не равны.

Comment: и правда - моя банальная невнимательность.
Спасибо!